# CakePHP: FriendsOfCake Search plugin not filtering on form submit

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I'm trying to set up the FriendsOfCake Search plugin (https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search) on CakePHP 3.1

I followed the instructions in the docs and set up a form in my index.ctp and try to filter only by title with a form.

But it seems like the forms post data is not processed by the method afterwards. There are no search parameters showing up in the URL.
If I type in the URL manually like: /paintings/index?title=blob it does filter correctly. So the plugin itself is working, I guess the problem is with the form, because after pressing the Submit button it just does nothing.

I'm new to CakePHP and have only limited knowledge so far. The informations in the Plugin documentation are very basic, so I'm not sure if it might assume some more settings without mentioning them?!

If I use the form to search for "blob" for example, the page is loading again without filtering and in the DebugKit it says: Post Data -- title blob.....But: no querystring data
(if that means anything..)

Can anybody help me figure out, what I'm doing wrong? I think there is something missing in my Controller or in the form settings in the view but I can't figure out what. Thanks for any help!

Here is my setup:

```php
class PaintingsTable extends Table
{
    public function searchConfiguration()
    {
    $search = new Manager($this);

    $search->like('title', [
                'field' => $this->aliasField('title')
        ]);

    return $search;

    }
```

```php
class PaintingsController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
       parent::initialize();

       if ($this->request->action === 'index') {
          $this->loadComponent('Search.Prg');
      }
    }

    public function index()
    {
    $query = $this->Paintings
        ->find('search', 
            $this->Paintings->filterParams($this->request->query))
        ->contain(['Artists']);

    $this->set('paintings', $this->paginate($query));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['paintings']);
    }
}
```

```php
In Paintings - index.ctp:

<?= $this->Form->create(); ?>

<?= $this->Form->input('title') ?>

<?= $this->Form->button('Filter', ['type' => 'submit']) ?>
<?= $this->Html->link('Reset', ['action' => 'index']) ?>

<?= $this->Form->end()?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok my bad! I now know what the problem was...it wasn't the code. If somebody comes across a similar issue:

I had set up CakeDC search plugin previously and had removed it from the required list in the composer.json but had forgotten to update composer, so that he actually removed it.

I noticed now that the CakeDC folder was still inside "vendor" folder. Since they both use the name "Search" as Plugin name, Cake must have been a bit confused. As soon as I updated composer it removed CakeDC plugin and the above setting worked just fine with the FriendsOfCake plugin.

Comment: I second that. I underwent an exact same scenario and removal of CakeDC's Search plugin fixed the PRG issues immediately.